# How to get UID and GID in rust-fuse?

Tags: filesystems, rust, fuse

I'm using [rust-fuse](https://crates.io/crates/fuse) to implement my own file system, and I need to get the UID and GID of the user who performs operations on the file system. 
I know that there is a `fuse_context` structure in the C libfuse, but I couldn't find it in rust-fuse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Version 0.3.0 of the fuse crate [documents the `Request` struct](https://docs.rs/fuse/0.3.0/fuse/struct.Request.html) as having [`uid`](https://docs.rs/fuse/0.3.0/fuse/struct.Request.html#method.uid) and [`gid`](https://docs.rs/fuse/0.3.0/fuse/struct.Request.html#method.gid) methods.